# memory game check for match with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am programming a memory game with plain JavaScript. My proplem is that I can't find a way to create a workable function to check for a match or not. here is my code and part of the html nd css.

```js
var matchCards = function() {
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-game');
  let first;
  let second;
  let matchCounter = 0;

  cards.forEach(function(card) {
    card.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (!first && !second) {
        first = card;
        card.classList.add('flip');
      } else if (first && !second) {
        second = card;
        card.classList.add('flip');

        if (first.innerHTML === second.innerHTML) {
          first = null;
          second = null;
          document.querySelector('.player-message').innerHTML = 'Match';
          document.querySelector('.player-message').style.color = '#55aa00';
          matchCounter++;
          if (matchCounter >= 12) {
            document.querySelector('.player-message').innerHTML = 'All cards matched';
            document.querySelector('.player-message').style.color = '#55aa00';
          } else {
            first.classList.remove('flip');
            second.classList.remove('flip');
            document.querySelector('.player-message').innerHTML = 'No Match';
            document.querySelector('.player-message').style.color = '#e4000f';
            setTimeout(() => {
              first.classList.remove('flip');
              second.classList.remove('flip');
              first = null;
              second = null
            }, 2000);
          }
        }
      }
    })
  });
}
matchCards();
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="game-board">
    <div class="memory-game">
      <img src="img/bob-omb.png" alt="bob omb" class="frontface">
      <img src="img/backface.png" alt="super mario question box" class="backface">
    </div>
    <div class="memory-game">
      <img src="img/bob-omb.png" alt="bob omb" class="frontface">
      <img src="img/backface.png" alt="super mario question box" class="backface">
    </div>
    <div class="memory-game">
      <img src="img/boo.png" alt="boo" class="frontface">
      <img src="img/backface.png" alt="super mario question box" class="backface">
    </div>
    <div class="memory-game">
      <img src="img/boo.png" alt="boo" class="frontface">
      <img src="img/backface.png" alt="super mario question box" class="backface">
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="message">
    <h1 class="player-message"></h1>
  </div>
</main>
```

I have researched and tried different resources on the internet. For example, stackoverflow youtube videos and other sites but none helped me. What I expect the memory game to do is when a match happens for the wor match to appear in green and a no match to appear in red and to flip back. What happens is that part of the function works it matches but when a no match happens nothing happens.

Comment: Comparing innerHTML is not very robust, because differences in whitespace will cause false failures. It would be better to give each tile an attribute that identifies its image, and compare that.

Comment: You're setting `first` and `second` to null, and then doing `self.classList.remove("flip")`. You need to remove the classes *before* you clear the variables. You're doing it correctly in the `setTimeout()`, why do you think you need to do the same thing earlier?